# Changing $|1-x|$ to $|x-1|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to get the limit $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{|1-x|}.$$ I think what I need to do is change $|1-x|$ to $|x-1|$ so I can cancel out one of the terms... but how do I get there?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The easiest way would be to consider two cases, when $1-x<0$ and $1-x \geq 0$.

Comment: You know that it’s always true that $|a-b|=|b-a|$, right? Thus, you already have $$\frac{(x-1)(x-1)}{|x-1|}$$ if you want it. However, $x-1$ and $|x-1|$ are equal if and only if $x-1\ge 0$, so the real issus is dealing with the two separate cases mentioned by @stochasm.

Answer (score 3):

First of all $(x-1)^2 = |x-1|^2$ for $x \neq 1$ (can you see why?). Secondly, $$|1 - x| = |-(x-1)| = |-1||x-1| = |x-1|.$$

Comment: Why wouldn't your statement be true for x=1? I get zero on both sides of the equal sign. By definition |x|=sqrt[x^2] and that applies on your statement as well (in squared form)

Comment: I never said it wasn't true for $x = 1$. In the context of the question, what happens at $x = 1$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

A property of absolute value is that

$|u| = |-u| \quad\forall \quad u$

From here we can switch up that denominator:

Let $u=1-x$

$|(1-x)| = |-(1-x)|$

$|1-x| = |x-1|$

Thus

$\dfrac{(x-1)(x-1)}{|1-x|} = \dfrac{(x-1)(x-1)}{|x-1|}$